# Sql express time Query

Tags: sql

am working with MS SQL express and Ignition SCADA by http://www.inductiveautomation.com/

In the SCADA package you are able to create tags from SQL query's. I am trying to use SQL tags to calculate the average packages per minute in a 30min time frame. I was able to do this with two tags and an expression

```
SELECT MAX(L8Total)
    FROM Slicing_tot
    WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

```
SELECT MIN(L8Total)
    FROM Slicing_tot
    WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

What I would like to do from here is store the expressions value and find the max and average for the last 30 days based on time. But I have no idea how to filter 30days of information at a certain time 
IE what was the max packages per minute we had at 10:30 from the last 30 days 
IE what was the average packages per minute we had at 11:45 form the last 30 days

Please keep in mind that I am new to SQL

Answer (score 0):

The following would select between 10 & 11 AM over those 30 days

```
SELECT MIN(L8Total)
    FROM Slicing_tot
    WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    and Datepart(hh,t_stamp) between 10 and 11
```

or you could compare the time part of the t_stamp to time

```
SELECT MIN(L8Total)
    FROM Slicing_tot
    WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
    and convert(time, t_stamp) between '10:30:00.000' and '10:31:00.000'
```

which would give you the results between 10:30 and 10:31 inclusive of the end points over the last 30 days.

Comment: you have not specified anything for last 30 days. You have last 30 minutes but not days.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I snagged his original code without inspecting it closely enough. I fixed it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, t_stamp)
       ,MAX(L8Total)
       ,MIN(L8Total)
    FROM Slicing_tot
    WHERE ( CONVERT(DATE, t_stamp) >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 30)
            AND CONVERT(DATE, t_stamp) <= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
          )
        AND ( CONVERT(TIME, @variable) >= '22:30'
              AND CONVERT(TIME, @variable) <= '23:00'
            )
    GROUP BY DATEPART(MINUTE, t_stamp)
```

`GETDATE()-30` will get you datetime of today minus 30 days ago. Since you are working with `datetime` field it is best to convert it to date to make sure that you get correct date range. Use of `>= and <=` is better than `between` because you is always clear what you doing. [Read @Aaron's blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

than for the second part just convert your datetime column to `time` to limit to specific range during the day.